# How to create a sound (wav) file with a list of amplitudes and their timestamps?

Tags: audio

I am trying a project where I have a list of amplitudes and their corresponding timestamps.

Is there any easy solution where these data can be converted into a playable sound?

It seems that if you have a list of amplitudes, you can create a wav file assuming a fixed frequency. However what if the data are at varying intervals?

Any popular framwork/software would be fine, python would be preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you acquainted with the concept of [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) (pulse code modulation)?

The audio data stream is going to be held in this form. I think a simple interpretation of what you describe would be to apply interpolated values from your amplitude data list to the PCM values that constitute your fixed frequency wave.

So, for example, from time1 to time2 for values1 to values2, use a [LERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) (linear interpolation) function to derive a volume factor to multiply against the corresponding PCM value.

Now, since a typical frame rate for PCM is 44100 fps, that is potentially a lot of interpolations between your amplitude list items. I'm wondering what the time interval is between the elements of your list of amplitudes. The deltas would have to be pretty small to have a chance of getting an interesting amplitude modulation effect. When the amplitude changes occur at audio rates, some strange harmonics can emerge, as the amplitude changes will in effect alter the carrier wave form. But anything slower than that, IDK.

I forgot to mention, you'll need a library in Python that can play PCM. In Java, we have the SourceDataLine that plays bytes that are generated directly from PCM. I know Android and Web Audio API have methods for directly playing back PCM. IDK about Python.